# How to open and close my SubWindow In QMdiArea in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

In QMidArea how to open a SubWindow? My Programs as follows. My intention to open/attach my second program in SubWindow. But Nothing Will happen. visible Only blank Window. How to resolve it?

How to attach my file in QMdi Sub-window ? and after my work, how to close the sub-window properly?

**Main Programme**

```
import sys,os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from sample_countrypage import Countrypage

class MainPage(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.setWindowTitle(" Sample Programme")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1600,600)
        self.Ui()
        self.show()

    def Ui(self):
        self.btn1=QPushButton("Country")
        self.btn1.setFixedSize(100, 30)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.countrypage)

        self.left_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.left_layout.setContentsMargins(3,5,5,3)
        self.left_layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.left_layout.addStretch()

        self.main_layout.setSpacing(5)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.left_layout)
        self.main_layout.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def countrypage(self):
        print("country page")
        self.countrywindow = Countrypage()
        subwindow = QMdiSubWindow()
        subwindow.setWidget(self.countrywindow)
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(subwindow)
        # subwindow.setFixedSize(500,500)
        subwindow.show()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainPage()
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Second Program**

```
import sys,os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Countrypage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Country Page")

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Accept")
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.result)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Re Enter")

        self.form_layout = QFormLayout()
        self.form_layout.addRow("Country",QLineEdit())
        self.form_layout.addRow("continent",QLineEdit())

        self.layout_btn = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_btn.addStretch()
        self.layout_btn.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.layout_btn.addWidget(self.btn2)

        self.layout_country = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_country.addLayout(self.form_layout)
        self.layout_country.addLayout(self.layout_btn)
        self.layout_country.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(self.layout_country)

    def result(self):
        print("bye")
        exec .close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    countrywin = Countrypage()
    countrywin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You never add `self.mdi` to the layout. Also, remove `self.setLayout(self.main_layout)`.

Comment: Its work fine, thhank you @ Musicanmante.  But how to close the subwindow only

Comment: @musicamante . its works fine. Thank you. And How to close the active subwindow? pls guide

Comment: I suggest you to study **all** the documentation of [QMdiArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html), as everything you need is there.

Comment: Can't able to understand. All in C language. if possible pls provide some tips @musicamante

Comment: That's C++, not C, and in any case the function names are the same in Python.

Comment: I really don't understand the difficulty. Go to the QMdiArea doc page linked above, use the search feature of your browser and look for "close": there's a function that is named **EXACTLY** like what you're looking for. I won't tell you what that function is, because frankly I'm a bit annoyed by the fact that instead of trying to go through the docs you chose to create another *identical* post. Sorry if I'm being harsh, but programming requires serious efforts in *studying the documentation*, you can't just browse around looking for already-made solutions for your code.

Comment: Frankly accept, I am not able to understand. so many searches, but I can't find out any hint.

Comment: as of my knowledge, it's not possible to close the mdi subwindow by itself ( by pressing a button in the subwindow).  the only way to close the subwindow by pressing "X" button . If we create a custom event method, then only we close the subwindow by itself. I dont know / no idea, How to create  that custom event. thats my problem @

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are two main issues with your code:

1. You never added the mdi area to the main layout (and you also tried to set the layout for the QMainWindow, which is forbidden);
2. `exec` is a python builtin, and has no `close` attribute; if you want to close the widget, you have to call `self.close()`;

Then, the [`setWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdisubwindow.html#setWidget) method of QMdiSubWindow *reparents* the widget:

> QMdiSubWindow takes temporary ownership of widget;

This means that if you want to close the sub window that contains the widget *from* that widget, you have to check the parent and eventually close it, as soon as you verify that it's an instance of QMdiSubWindow.

```
class Countrypage(QWidget):
    # ...
    def result(self):
        print("bye")
        # ensure that the parent is actually a subwindow
        if isinstance(self.parent(), QMdiSubWindow):
            self.parent().close()
        else:
            self.close()
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom signal and connect that when creating the subwindow.

```
class Countrypage(QWidget):
    closeRequested = pyqtSignal()
    # ...
    def result(self):
        print("bye")
        self.closeRequested.emit()


class MainPage(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def countrypage(self):
        print("country page")
        self.countrywindow = Countrypage()
        subwindow = QMdiSubWindow()
        subwindow.setWidget(self.countrywindow)
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(subwindow)
        subwindow.show()
        self.countrywindow.closerequested.connect(subwindow.close)
```

If you want to close the *active* subwindow from the mdi area (or outside of it) and no matter what that sub window is, just call [`self.mdi.closeActiveSubWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#closeActiveSubWindow).

Note that if you're going to create multiple `Countrypage` instances, there's no point in creating an instance attribute (`self.countrywindow`) as it will always be overwritten as soon as another instance will be created. Adding the widget to the subwindow and that subwindow to the mdi area will automatically create a persistent reference (due to the parenting); if you need a python reference to existing pages, then create a list as an instance member in the `__init__` (eg. `self.pages = []`) and add the new instances to that list.